# How to show that $L^p \subset L^1$ given a finite positive measure space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space with positive measure and $\mu(X) < \infty$. And let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function and $1<p<\infty$.

(a) how to prove

$\int_X |f|^p d\mu <\infty$ can imply $\int_X |f| d\mu <\infty$? i.e., $L^p \subset L^1$. The hint is Holder inequality. But I don't know how to use. Here p=p, q=1, which makes me stuck.

(b) Show that the condition $\mu(X) < \infty$ cannot be dropped. Do we have a counter example?

Holder inequality: $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space with positive measure , $1<p<\infty$, $1<q<\infty$, $1/p + 1/q = 1$, $f \geq 0, g \geq 0$ are measurable, then

$$\int_X fg d\mu \leq ||f||_p ||g||_q$$

Comment: what? 1/p + 1/0 is *not* 1. And yes, there are many counterexamples. Check examples you know that belong to $L^p$ on say $\Bbb R$

Comment: I suggest that you state the Holder inequality. This may help answering the question.

Comment: So take $g$ constant equal to one in the Holder inequality, as you stated it. What do you obtain?

Comment: Just split the integration set into two $X_1 = \{ |f(x)| < 1 \}$ and $X_2 =\{ |f(x)| >= 1 \}$. On the first one use the fact that measure is finite, on the second that $|f(x)| <|f(x)|^p$

Comment: Note that $f\in L^p$ and the constant function $1\in L^q$ since $X$ has finite measure. Thus $f=f1\in L^1$ by Hölder

Answer (score 2):

Let $u \in \mathcal{L}^q,\,q >1$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$. Note that $(1-1/q)$ and $1/q$ are (reciprocals of) conjugate numbers. Furthermore, $|u|\in \mathcal{L}^q$ and $1 \in \mathcal{L}^{1/(1-1/q)}$ since $\mu(X)<\infty$. By Hoelder's inequality we have
$$\|u\|_1=\|1\cdot |u|\|_1\leq \|1\|_{1/(1-1/q)}\|u\|_q=\mu(X)^{1-1/q}\|u\|_q$$
Therefore $\mathcal{L}^q\subset \mathcal{L}^1$. To see that this fails if $\mu$ is not finite: consider $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}},\nu)$ where $\nu$ is the counting measure. Consider $u(n)=1/n$. Then
$$\|u\|_1=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}=\infty,\,\|u\|_2^2=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$
So $u\in \mathcal{L}^2$ but $u \notin \mathcal{L}^1$.

Comment: I know my question is silly, but I need to know the definition more precisely. When we say $u \in \mathcal{L}^q$, what does this mean? What is $u$? A real number? I know every time when we say $\mathcal{L}^q$ space, we are talking about q norm.

Comment: @Mariana $\mathcal{L}^q$ is a function space and $u$ an element of it